# Makefile: dependency on many files

Tags: performance, makefile

I have about 30K files and I want to batch-convert them to another format in a complicated Makefile. When I list the files explicitly, GNUMake chokes (or at least runs very long). When I make the dependency on just one of the 30K files, it works but of course it won't rebuild the conversion when some of the other files changes...

How should I go about this?

Comment: Maybe try breaking up the file list into smaller groups of files, make a dependency for each smaller group, and then have one main dependency that has all the sub-dependencies as its dependency?  Maybe it's a per-dependency limit that's blowing up.

Comment: You don't properly explain what you are doing. If I can see the makefile. I could help with simplifying it, and getting it to work.